# How to compare two playlists in YouTube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I want to download videos of two playlists from YouTube (100+ videos in each one) but they have common videos. How can I compare these playlists and find the repeated videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way! First, export your playlists as two different csv files using this: https://www.tunemymusic.com/YouTube-to-File.php. Then, using Excel, put the "track name" column of the two playlists on a single Excel sheet. Then, you can [highlight duplicates across the two columns](https://trumpexcel.com/find-and-remove-duplicates-in-excel/#Finding_and_Highlight_Duplicates_in_Multiple_Columns).